# How show label message in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Could you please help me in displaying message after certain work done like 1 record deleted after 
deleting data from database.
In JFrame there is a method like setVisible(true), similarly is there any way in JSP?

Comment: `What have you tried?`                                             Where is the data being manipulated, where are you getting the result you want to display, in the view (actual JSP page) or in the controller (the servlet) or the actual backend logic (the java classes) ? Also can you post the code you are using to get the results.

Comment: I am doing a mini project, i am beginners for JSP, i have jsp page which i am using just for UI there is form that form action goes to servlet for certain action.for example if i insert a data from form i need to display a message saying like "one record inserted successfully"

Comment: look up jstl tag library

Answer (score 3):

JSP is just a HTML code generator. All you need to do is to make sure that it generates HTML the way you want. You can use [JSTL core tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) to control the flow of HTML code generation.

For example, assuming that you've a servlet which sets a message like follows,

```
request.setAttribute("message", "Record successfully deleted");
```

then you can conditionally display it in JSP as follows with help of JSTL `<c:if>`.

```html
<c:if test="${not empty message}">
    <span class="message">${message}</span>
</c:if>
```

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains Hello World example with similar validation/messaging approach
- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) - contains info how to install and use JSTL

Comment: BalusC sorry i am beginners for jsp i could not understand. Can you please tell me more in detail.